# Parse output in python to count number of occurences

Tags: python, shell, parsing

I have a python script that makes a curl command and reads the output into a variable called `output`

The output is something similar to this:

```
"endpoint1: {
    "[service1]endpoint": {
    },
    "[service1]endpoint": {
    },
    "[service2]endpoint": {
    },
    "[service2]endpoint": {
    }
  }
"endpoint2": {
    "[service1]endpoint": {
    }
  },
```

What I need to do is parse this output to count the unique strings between [] and print out the occurrences. So something like this:

```
service1 3 
service2 2
```

Any help on how I would go about doing this. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like JSON to me. Try a JSON reader.

Comment: Trying to use regex as follows with `re.search(r'\[(.*)\]', output).group(1)`, but this only gives me an output of service1

Comment: @AChampion this is what I have so far: `re.findall(r'\[(.*)\]', output)` which gives me a list of all the strings between the [], like ['service1', 'service1', 'service2', 'service2', 'service1']. Now I need to count the number of occurrences of the unique strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input isn't valid JSON, use the following approach with `collections.Counter` object and `re.findall()` function:

```
result = collections.Counter(re.findall(r'\[([^]]+)\]', output))
print(result)
```

The output:

```
Counter({'service1': 3, 'service2': 2})
```

Comment: any way to format the output so you have a row for each string and its number of occurrences?

Comment: @ashkash, I didn't understand your comment